# It is possible to keyframing strings?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, keyframes

I have a Geometry Nodes that shows a string. And I need to change this string during the animation.

It is possible to change this string like you do to change an integer value?

In my example I change 'col pantalla' during the animation.
Now I need to change 'Temperatura' like the same way.
[image]

It is possible without changing my Geometry Nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect both of your strings to a switch node and animate the switch checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I don't like this way because I need to change a lot of times the string and the Geometry Node result will be extended.